# How do I dynamically display images as background images for a post page in mongoose/node?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, ejs, multer

This is my first question here, and I'm a novice to Nodejs. I hope someone can help me out with this. I am creating a simple blog website using mongoose, node, ejs, and express, and I want to upload images using a multipart form, and then save that image to a local directory so it can be used as a background-image dynamically on my individual post page. I've tried express-fileupload and Multer but the image could not display in the background. However it get's saved to the local directory. What am I missing or not doing right? Here's a snippet of my code:

My sever code

```
//jshint esversion:6

const express = require("express");

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const ejs = require("ejs");

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const multer  = require('multer');
const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, 'public/posts');

 },
 filename: function (req, file, cb) {
     cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
 }});


 const upload = multer({ storage: storage});
```

Database code:

```
const  PostSchema =  new mongoose.Schema({
title: String,

description: String,

content: String,

username: String,

image: String,

createdAt: {
    type: Date,

    default: new Date()
}
});

const Post = mongoose.model("post", PostSchema);
```

Compose route:

```
app.get("/compose", function(req,res){

res.render("compose");

});

app.post('/compose', function (req, res) {
  const post = new Post({
      title: req.body.title,
      username: req.body.username,
      content: req.body.content,
      image: req.file.image
      });

  post.save(function(err){

     if(!err){

      res.redirect("/");
    }
     });
  });

app.get('/post/:id', function(req,res){

const requestedPostId = req.params.id;

 Post.findOne(

  {_id: requestedPostId}, 

  function(err, foundPost) {

       if (!err) {

       res.render("post", {post: foundPost});
    }

  });
});
```

Ejs code for my posts:

```
<header class="masthead" style="background-image:url('<%=post.image'%>)">

<div class="overlay"></div>

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">

      <div class="post-heading">

        <h1><%=post.title%></h1>

        <span class="meta">Posted by

              <a href="#"><%=post.username%></a>

              on <%=post.createdAt.toDateString()%>

            </span>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>


</div>
```

Form:

```
      <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control-file">

    </div>
```

Look forward to any corrections!
Thanks

Comment: did you check that your image name is saved to database or not?  Even, your image name is read it won't be shown on the page as your url address is wrong. It should be `background-image:url('/posts/<%=post.image'%>)"` as your image container folder name is `posts`

Comment: Thanks for your respond Afrida! Yes the images are been saved into the posts/ folder and I can see it saved there. However, it just wouldn't work when am using ejs tags. It works when I use the express-edge template. I've tried it using the path you provided, but I got the same result using ejs tags.

Comment: @Ben Can you add in the displayed error that you are facing.

Comment: Hey guy's thanks for all your help. I was able to figure it out using express-handlebars template engine and express-fileupload. Everything is working fine.